# "Take on your enemies" – What does that mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I heard the phrase "Take on your enemies" announced in a news conference today. Could you help me understand what it means?

Comment: Giving us more context would be nice; even though "your enemies" is already a good clue, the whole phrase could mean something entirely different in an uncommon context. The basic idea of "take on" is "deal with it" or "do something about it".

Answer (score 2):

To take on someone or something is to confront them.

If you take on your enemies, you confront them with the goal of defeating them.

Answer (score 2):

Take on your enemies means - go, deal with them (bravely?).

It's used as a transitive verb.

> [Take on (tr. v)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20on) - to begin to perform or deal with

Note that there are other uses of it on the page as well.