# What does "Take on Me" mean in A-ha's song?

Tags: idioms, lyrics

Doe it mean the same as "Take on your enemies" in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/16831/15691)?
Or does it mean to *confront me as an enemy*?

I can't figure out the meaning even from the context of the whole song...

*Update*:
After reading the lyric again, I am not sure what "**Take me on**" means as well...

Full lyric.
[image]

Comment: Why don't you post some context, like some lyrics... Or do you want us to do the work of asking the question as well as answering it?

Comment: I guess it was my mistake thinking that everyone knew the song... I will post the lyric.

Comment: I think interpretation of song lyrics is Off Topic. And as I native speaker I have to say I've got absolutely no idea what if anything *take on me* is supposed to mean there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because song lyrics do not necessarily adhere to standard word meanings, uses, or even forms, and so there is no definitive way to know whether a particular lyric has a particular intended meaning or if it is merely gibberish chosen because it sounds interesting to the lyricist.

Comment: [take on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+on). *To accept a new task, and to oppose someone in competition.* The first one seems most likely: *Accept the new task of loving me* (and if you watch the award-winning video, you might throw in *even though it may be difficult.* Also in the video, the 2nd definition can come into play, when the bad guys appear) But songwriters didn't usually write songs with videos in mind. And videos do not often have anything to do with what the song is acually about. So, it is anyone's guess. And you are free to interpret the song as you like.

Comment: Sounds good.  As for the alternating of "take me on" and "take on me", I theorize that these three young Norwegians in London were amused at how one can literally "turn a phrase" inside out just for fun.